# Firestore storing partial data to document

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a issue with data saving to Firestore. I'm passing a list of url's to be saved to the document.

[data sent in the following format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lpkt.jpg)

But it saving only the first data
[firestore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv5cM.png)

what may be issue? Please help.

update button click handler

```
handleUpdate=()=>{
        const promises = [];
        let files=[];
        const {fileURLs,sp_License,sp_PilotsLicense}=this.state;

        let err = this.validate();
        if (!err) {
           this.setState({ loading: true,disChecked:false })

            // const Lfilename = this.state.sp_Name + '_' + new Date().getTime();
            //     const uploadTask = storage.ref('License/' + Lfilename).put(sp_License);

             let orgFile='';

            const promise1=this.uploadTaskPromise().then((res)=>{
               console.log(res)
               orgFile=res
            });
            promises.push(promise1)
            console.log(orgFile)

            //promises.push(this.uploadTaskPromiseMulti());
            const promise2=this.uploadTaskPromiseMulti().then((res)=>{
                console.log(res)
                files=res
             });
             promises.push(promise2)
             console.log(promise2)


                Promise.all(promises).then(tasks => {
                    console.log('all uploads complete');
                    console.log(this.state)
                    if(this._mounted)
                    {
                        //this.saveData();
                        //console.log(orgFile.data)
                        this.setState({ 
                            fileURLs: files, -- here fileurls gets updated
                            sp_License:orgFile,
                        },()=>{
                            console.log(this.state)
                            this.saveData();
                        });
                    }

                });

        }
    }
```

code of saveData method - I'm using react redux firebase method for saving data

```
saveData=()=>{
        let uid = this.props.auth.uid;
        let keysToRemove = ["loading", "checked", "disChecked", "open", "message",
        "sp_NameError", "sp_PhoneError", "sp_emailError", 'usr_org_LicenseNumberError', 
        'sp_LicenseError','usr_org_StateConveredError','usr_org_DistConveredError',
        'sp_NumberofEquipmentsError','sp_NumberofDronePilotsError','sp_PilotsLicense',
        'sp_NumberofEquipmentsOwnedError','sp_ToolError','processingToolServiceError',
        'processingToolDomainError','modalopen','EquipmentCount',
        'PilotsCount','buttonName','isReady','redirect']
       let newState = Object.entries({...this.state}).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
         if(!keysToRemove.includes(key)){
             obj[key] = value
         }
         return obj
        }, {})
       console.log(newState)

        this.props.UpdateUserDetails(uid, newState,this.successMessage)

    }
```

Action code

```
export const UpdateUserDetails= (id, droneSPDetails,func) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore()
        firestore.collection('web_Users')
            .doc(id)
            .set({
                 ...droneSPDetails,
                sp_UpdatedOn: new Date(),
                //sp_Status:"pending",
                sp_ActiveFlag:"1",
            },{ merge: true })
            .then(() => {
                func();
                dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_DRONESP', droneSPDetails });

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code? it's hard to tell just from that. I would check whether you accidentally sliced the array somehow

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to add those urls to the database. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Barak I have provided the code

Comment: @AlexMamo I have provided the code..

Comment: please help me to find the solution. I'm not able to understand whats wrong with the code.. plz help..